# How to programatically loops through files and require each one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm in Node (gulp actually) trying to programatically loop through files and require each one. But I keep getting an error that Browserify doesn't have a pipe method. This doesn't happen when I explicitely write each require statement. Here's my code:

```
var bStream = browserify({
         entries: [options.JSX_DEST + '/main']
     })
     .require('react')
     .require('react-addons');

fs.readdirSync(options.JSX_DEST).forEach(function(file){
        bStream.require(options.JSX_DEST + '/' + file);
    });

bStream.bundle({debug: false});
bStream.pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.JSX_DEST));
```

Any ideas on the correct way to do this? Just for clarification the following *works* if I chain my bundle statement in the first line but this requires I explicitly write each require line whereas I want to do it programatically.

```
var bStream = browserify({
        entries: [options.JSX_DEST + '/main']
    })  
    .require('react')
    .require('react-addons')
    .bundle({debug: false});
    bStream
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.JSX_DEST));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to assign the result of the function call back to `bstream`:

```
fs.readdirSync(options.JSX_DEST).forEach(function(file){
    bStream = bStream.require(options.JSX_DEST + '/' + file);
});

bStream.bundle({debug: false});
  .pipe(source('bundle.js')) // <- call .pipe on the result of .bundle!
  .pipe(gulp.dest(options.JSX_DEST));
```

---

Just to be clear, if you use method chaining such as

```
var x = foo().bar().baz();
```

then the equivalent version without chaining would be

```
var x = foo();
x = x.bar();
x = x.baz();
```

**not**

```
var x = foo();
x.bar();
x.baz();
```

Notice that `x` would still have the value that `foo()` returned, not the value that `baz()` returned.

Comment: Great answer - thanks. For some reason I was thinking of it in a class-based manner which isn't correct here.